# How to add Dynamic Intent to any Activity which is decided by the backend in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am looking for a way to Add an Intent to a List of Items or Buttons or Banners and the Intent to the Activity is decided by the Server.

Take an Example. I have a List of Items(Suppose 4) with an Image that is coming from the Server. Each Item takes the user to a different Activity using Intent. I can pre-set the Intent to the item according to the position to the Item. 1st item takes to Activity A ... and 4th to Activity D.

I want to add the Intent to the items dynamically. Like if I change the position or suppose change the image of the item(the intent should also change according to the item).

There is one way I can think of, I send the Activity class Name along with the data and make the Intent accordingly with the bundle also.

```
public void launchActivity(Class<?> clss, Bundle b) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), clss);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Is there any other way of doing it. Could DeepLinking help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

```java
private Class[] mClasses = {
    One.class,
    Two.class,
    Three.class,
    Four.class
};
```

Be careful, your list should be `mClasses.length>=yourList.size()`
And, on your item click listener:

```java
onItemClick(YourList item) {
   new Intent(getActivity(), mClasses[item.getPosition]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName`

However, in that case your backend will have to know exact package name of each class to use.

Or you can use some ordinals, to use in a switch case.

```
switch(activityNumber){
   case One: new Intent(getActivity(), One.class);
   ...
 }
```